# Flutter image load from Firebase Realtime database

Tags: flutter, firebase, image, firebase-realtime-database

could you have a solution, I trying to load an image from the Firebase Realtime database in my project, and the code looks good and doesn't respond to any errors, but my app shows that my database is empty.
So it shows No data available.
I can't find a solution to why the image and name won't load.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:recco_app/widgets/type_vechile_item.dart';

class TypeVehicleScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String selectedCountry;
  final String selectedType;

  const TypeVehicleScreen({
    super.key, 
    required this.selectedCountry,
    required this.selectedType,
  });

  @override
  State<TypeVehicleScreen> createState() => _TypeVehicleScreenState();
}

class _TypeVehicleScreenState extends State<TypeVehicleScreen> {
  late DatabaseReference _vehiclesRef;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _vehiclesRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref('Countries/${widget.selectedCountry}/Types/${widget.selectedType}/Vehicles');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.selectedType),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _vehiclesRef.onValue,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(child: Text('Error loading data.'));
          } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.snapshot.value == null) {
            return const Center(child: Text('No data available.'));
          } else {
            Map<String, dynamic> vehiclesData =
                (snapshot.data!.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>)
                    .cast<String, dynamic>();
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: vehiclesData.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                String vehicleName = vehiclesData.keys.elementAt(index);
                String imageUrl = vehiclesData[vehicleName]['image'];
                return TypeVechileItem(imageUrl: imageUrl, title: vehicleName);
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you `print(imageUrl)` what does it output? And if that is the correct URL for your image, what happens if you replace the `StreamBuilder` with just `TypeVechileItem(imageUrl: "thatSameUrl", title: "thatSameVehiceName")`? If you get the same result with this, the problem has nothing to do with the database, and you can simplify the question to rule that out.